# Export VBA macro using Vb.net

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, excel-interop

I have the following situation:

On the one side, I have my `Vb.net` application, from which I can access/run the macros which are stored in a Excel Workbook (`*.xlsm`). Thanks to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` no big deal.

I can simply access the macros via `xl.App.Run(macroname)` or even with parameters.

Now **I want to see/parse the code of the macros itself** to further analyse them - is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

If you can run an Excel VBA macro from VB.NET, then you can run Ron de Bruin's code described here:

[Import and Export VBA Code](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm)

Comment: thank you for the link but the problem with this solution is, that I have to adept the existing makros.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
' compare the selection.
Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C5")
' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _
' Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C5")
'
' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
' each cell in CompareRange.
For Each x In Selection
For Each y In CompareRange
If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
Next y
Next x
```

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for your contribution. After submitting code, please be sure to (p)review your post for formatting issues. In this case, your code was rendering as normal body text and was very difficult to read. I’ve updated it; take a look at the markdown so you can apply similar formatting in the future.